# VirtualBox - Failed to open a session for the virtual machine. No error info

Tags: 13.10, virtualbox

I'm trying to start an Ubuntu 13.10 virtual machine from a saved state. This works correctly if I restart the virtual machine a few moments after stopping, but not if I start it a few minutes later. I then get this error:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Thesis.
>
> No error info.
>
> Result Code: NS_ERROR_CALL_FAILED (0x800706BE)
>   Component: ProgressProxy
>   Interface: IProgress {c20238e4-3221-4d3f-8891-81ce92d9f913}

You can find the [logfile here](http://pastebin.com/SWUFy5PR).

- VirtualBox VM 4.3.10 r93012
- Host: Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit Desktop
- Guest: Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit Desktop
- Guest additions are installed and I have one auto-mounting shared folder.

So far I have tried upgrading VirtualBox (from the one in Ubuntu software center to 4.3.10 from the VirtualBox website) and re-building the virtual machine from scratch.

What is the next step in debugging this? I get "No error info." in the error dialog and I can't find any errors in the log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was solved by disabling 3D acceleration in Settings > Display > Extended Features.

This problem occurred with an integrated Intel HD Graphics 4000 GPU on a Intel Core i5 3570K.

Comment: We use multiple versions of VirtualBox and we noticed that this happens on version 4.3.16 but doesn't on newer ones, so upgrading may also resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into this issue on Ubuntu 15.04 with a Windows 7 guest. In my case the solution was to **enable** 3D Acceleration (*Settings* > *Display* > *Extended Features*).